# не работает функция trim PHP

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает trim?

```
<?php
$text2 = "Всем привет, этот текст используется для str_replace, сейчас мы будем удалять все буквы а и б, поехали?";

$text2 = trim($text2, "е");

echo $text2;
?>
```

Должен удалять все буквы е, но при выводе $text2 пишет вот это:

> �сем привет, этот текст используется для str_replace, сейчас мы будем удалять все буквы а и б, поехали?

Comment: во-1х, trim удаляет не все, а только по краям строк, это не аналог str_replace. Во-2х, у вас проблемы с кодировкой

Comment: trim удаляет в [начале и конце строки](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php)

Comment: Всё, понятно:D  
А почему с кодировкой проблемы, в чём причина и как это исправить?

Comment: *"А почему с кодировкой проблемы, в чём причина и как это исправить?"* --- использовать функции с приставкой mb_